How is the validator parallelized?
I was surprised to find that a Bank's load_and_execute_transactions method does not execute transactions in parallel (see here).
The purpose of an Entry is to batch transactions that can be executed in parallel. Looking at the ReplayStage, I see its just a thread pool of Banks.
So multiple Banks can run in parallel but if the validator is processing an entry, how is that parallelized if a single Bank cannot execute all the transactions in parallel?
Just trying to understand how parallelization works, any input is appreciated.

As you noticed, ReplayStage has a thread pool to execute transactions, which eventually gets used in the blockstore at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/cdff19c7807b006dd63429114fb1d9573bf74172/ledger/src/blockstore_processor.rs#L324-L366
It's a bit confusing to follow, but from what I can see, during replay, the algorithm tries to execute as many entries as possible in parallel, but won't schedule individual entries to be executed on multiple threads, even though they technically can be.
So I think you're right and that some threads may be underutilized, likely to prioritize replaying multiple forks at once over finishing one fork more quickly.
Note: this doesn't cover the unified scheduler, which appears to work through a totally different method
